# Android Google Maps Create Button

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a Google Maps app. I want to create a button, when I click it, map will show my location. I made some research but I couldn't find an answer. I enabled current location button on map but that's not what I want. 
This is the button I created in `activity_main.xml`

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCurrent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="onClick_Current"
            android:text="Current" />
```

And my method

```
public void onClick_Current(View v)
{

 // Code goes here
}
```

I am new at android so can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You need first get your location `latitude,longitude` as `String`, such that:

```
String location = 47.6,-122.3;
```

Then in your `OnClick_Current` method add following code:

```
Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q", location)
                .build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't call " + location + ", no receiving apps installed!");
        }
```

For more details, please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps).